# Changing textboxes' color when NULL using functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, colors, textbox

I have a minor question to ask. I would like to change a few textboxes' background color to RED from WHITE if they're left NULL after clicking on a "validate" button. It is prohibited to add any Classes or IDs into the input. I was given a hint to use "document.querySelectorAll"

The below is my HTML code:

```
<div id="formtovalidate">
    <div><input type="text" value="Billy Bob" /> Name</div>
    <div><input type="text" value="" /> Email Address</div>
    <div><input type="text" value="98195" /> ZIP Code</div>
    <div><input type="text" value="" /> Mailing Address</div>
    <div><input type="text" value="" /> Telephone Number</div>
    <div><input type="password" value="abc123" /> Password</div>
</div>

<div><button id="validate">validate</button></div>
```

This is a code I tried:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('validate').onclick = checkFilled;
}

function checkFilled() {
    var input = document.getElementByID('myText');
    if(input.value == '')
    {
        input.style.background = 'red';
    }
    else
    {
        input.style.background = '';
    }
}
```

But this isn't allowed cause I've added IDs to each input boxes. I also tried using document.querySelectorAll. But it just can't work. Did I do anything wrong?

Please help me with this >.< Thank you guys! Cheers ;)

Comment: then why is query tagged with the question..? did you do any sort of research regarding the given hint..? did you try anything..?

Comment: __I was given a hint to use "document.querySelectorAll"__ In short you don't know How to do it. Start [LEARN JAVASCRIPT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript) Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#validate').click(function (e) {
        $('input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
        });

    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rFEER/48/)

JS Solution

In HTML `<button id="validate" onclick="checkFilled() ">validate</button>`

```
function checkFilled() {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input')
    for (var i = 0;i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].value == '') {
        input[i].style.background = 'red';
    } 
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rFEER/49/)

Comment: The OP was given some sort of assignment and a hint to help with doing it. without doing any sort of research or learning, he directly comes here and posted it. Spoon feeding won't be going to help anyone in longer terms. Questions without any research effort doesn't fit SO either. my humble opinion.

Comment: @user3774597 please do not dump code in comments. edit the question and update it there so that it's readable and will get more attention. you might want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @user3774597 Glad to help you.!! Search around to get info before post

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#validate').click(function (e) {
        $("#formtovalidate").find("input").each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == "") {
                input.css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });
    });
});
```